# Add admin username & password to the keychain

Tags: macos, password, keychain, administrator

How can the admin's username password, be remembered or added it to the keychain so these annoying prompts would be less frequent?

[image: prompt for admin credentials]

The app referenced here (Anvil) is not relevant.
I'm looking for a way to loosen up the the prompts for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can go about this the other way around.

Open Keychain Access and find the items you need and modify that item so that the app in question is white listed for the password or credential being used.

[image: Access Control from within Keychain Access]

Once you are in Access Control - you can white list certain apps or all apps. This can be automated if the dialog has an "always remember" or "don't ask again" check mark so that the ACL can be set properly without needing to enter Keychain Access from the back end on a case by case basis.

Comment: Another workaround is to make the admin password BLANK so you can just press return. This also makes it secure since you can't sudo with no password or log in remotely using ssh although the in person ramifications of having no password for the Admin user (or via screen sharing) makes this a poor choice for the long haul.

Comment: It appears from the screenshot that the user is not an admin. Admin users have their user name pre-populated on these popups. So the blank password will still be a slight annoyance. Technically running logged in as root should remove all such popups but that would be a very dangerous proposition indeed. I wonder if global defaults can be adjusted for such things?